# How to return 2 char pointers from function?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I need to create a function that **takes in** a `pointer to part of a string` and **returns** a pointer to the beginning of the `first word in the string` and a pointer to the `string after the word`.

The characters of a word are defined as upper case and lower case letters, and characters like '-'.

Mainly, I'm not sure how we would return two pointers from a function.

I also don't have the best grasp on pointers so I'm looking for any tips on what a function like this might look like.

Comment: if you will pass a string pointer in c you must pass from the beginning of string not in medel !! because you can't reach the start of it ( _unless you have the string start with spical char_)

...
**Strings in C** and Most other languages it end with null `'\0'` character so you could know when the end comming  but you can't know where it start if you don't have explicit pointer to start character
...
and how you could return multi pointer you could see the answar of @Adam

Comment: @IbramReda- this is not what he is asking! read the question again. he is passing a string and need to get back pointers to different places in the passed string.

Comment: @Jack M Can you add an example of what you expect ?

Comment: @IbramReda - in C you can do what ever u like. includes the passing of pointers to the middle of a string!

Comment: @IbramReda My goal is to pass in a line like "hello there, i'm hungry!" and return a pointer to 'h', the beginning of the first word and a pointer to the rest of the string starting at 't'. And then rinse and repeat until ive extracted every word out of the line.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work though.

Comment: Suggest using the function: `strtok()`  as it will return a pointer to the *first* word and keep track of beginning of next word, so your code doesn't need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first approach**

One way to do it is by returning the result in the function arguments (by Dereferencing the callee pointers, which he need to provide in the calling statement)

```
void process_my_string(const char* userString, char** ptr_firstWord, char** ptr_stringAfter);
```

how we call it ?

```
char* pfirst = NULL;
char* plast = NULL;
const char* str="hello c pointers";

process_my_string(str, &pfirst, &plast);
```

**second approach**

one of the pointers will be returned in the return value and the other in the function passed argument (like the first approach):

```
char* process_my_string(const char* userString, char** ptr_stringAfter);
```

how we call it ?

```
char* pfirst = NULL;
char* plast = NULL;
const char* str="hello c pointers";

pfirst = process_my_string(str, &plast);
```

**third approach**

return the pointers (both of them) in a `structure` or an `array` of pointers. I have chossed to return in my `s_return` structure below:

```
typedef struct{
   char* p_first;
   char* p_after;
} s_return;
```

now the function becomes:

```
s_return process_my_string(const char* userString);
```

how we call it ?

```
const char* str="hello c pointers";
s_return my_return = process_my_string(str);

/*access the pointers*/
printf("%s\n", my_return.p_first);
printf("%s\n", my_return.p_last);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Also, using the first approach, say I extract a string like  char *word = "hello" within the function, to save the address of that word do I write ptr_firstWord = &word?

Comment: Good answer about "returning" multiple values in one function. But you do not answer to how to get a pointer to the begin of a string by another pointer to the middle of the string

Comment: @JackM - you cant do such thing in c, `char* word = "hello";`  this must be a **const char**,    `const char* word="hello";`. following first approach, if you pass `char* ptr_firstWord;` the the pointer itself is the address in the  original string.

Comment: @Sunchock - This is not the question. this is the question "Mainly, I'm not sure how we would return two pointers from a function??"

Comment: @JackM - glad to help. if my answer helped you please accept it (push the vote up and grey V nearby my answer).

Comment: @Adam my mistake, i misunderstood

Comment: @Sunchock - thank you for the comment. its okay. if you think it is a good answer i would be glad if you vote it up. thanks.

Comment: @Sunchock - feel free not to vote bro. all of stackoverflow users are here for contribution and reputation. :-). any way if you alreay vote. thank you.

Comment: Will I need to malloc the strings I expect to return?

Comment: @Adam I agree with you, just a little joke ;-)
I've already upvote for your answer

Comment: @JackM - no. because in the function `process_my_string` you are just returning a pointer to some place in the already allocated string by the user which he passed in `userString`.

Comment: Oh okay, So once ive worked out what indexes I need to split the string would I be able to use something like strncpy(*ptr_firstWord... and strncpy(*ptr_stringAfter...?

Comment: @JackM - `char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);`.  `ptr_firstWord` is a pointer no need for deref (deref will yield a char). just passit as is. 
`char dest[24]; `
`strncpy(dest, ptr_firstWord, ....);`

Comment: That makes sense, but If I want to return a pointer to the start of a word in the  userString  would I then assign ptr_firstWord = &userString[i]. This is the main thing i'm trying to wrap my head around.